# Probability of Landing Heads on Certain Toss/Summing to 1

Tags: probability

> You are tossing a coin and it has a probability of p to show heads on any given toss. You keep on tossing the coin until you see a heads. Let X represent the number of tosses until you see the first heads.
>
> 1. Find the probability that X is odd.
>
> 2. Find the probability that X is even, DO NOT USE QUESTION 1.

So I got answers for both questions but the probabilities should sum to one and I am not getting that which I am confused on.  We will say the probability of getting heads is $P(Heads)=p$ and tails is $P(Tails)=1-p$.  This is a geometric series so with $p$ being the first term and $p^2$ being the common ratio, I got $\frac{p}{1-p^2}$ for the probability of landing heads on the odd toss.  Meanwhile, a similar logic is used for finding the probability of heads on the even toss (now this is an arithmetic geometric series) except I got $\frac{(1-p)^2}{1-(1-p)^2}$.  So I got these two probabilities but they do not sum to 1 which I am confused since shouldn't they?  So either I did something wrong with the probabilities or I am just summing incorrectly.

Comment: You are counting that first $H$?  Well, then the  probability that $X=1$ is $p$, the probability that $X=3$ is $(1-p)^2p$ and so on, so I don't see a ratio of $p^2$ here.

Comment: If you have heads on odd toss for example first toss it's p, on the 3rd toss $p^3$, on the fifth $p^5$ etc. That's how I got ratio of $p^2$.  For an even toss for example 2 is $(1-p)^2$, for the fourth toss $(1-p)^4$ etc.  So common ratio for odd toss is p and even is $(1-p)^2$.  Correct or no?

Comment: No, that's not correct.  In order to see the first $H$ on toss $\#3$ the only path is $TTH$ which has probability $(1-p)^2p$.

Comment: Note:  you should really specify what exactly you mean by $X$.  Do you count that last $H$ or not?  Specifically, if the path is $TTH$ do you see that as $X=3$ or as $X=2$?  It's easy to pass from one calculation to the other, of course, but you should be clear which one you intend.

Comment: I fixed it to the first heads

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  If the path is $TTH$, do you see that as $X=3$ or as $X=2$?

Comment: When you see the first heads it's not on the 2nd toss but the 3rd toss in your example so it would be $X=3$

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured (and that's what the posted solution assumes as well).  I suggest editing your post to reflect that.  Again, people sometimes use the term "geometric distribution" to refer to the number of trials $\textit {before}$ you get a success, not counting the first success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(X\equiv 0 \pmod{2}) = p\sum_{n\ge 0}(1-p)^{2n+1} = \dfrac{p(1-p)}{1-(1-p)^2}$$

$$P(X \equiv 1\pmod{2}) = p\sum_{n\ge 0} (1-p)^{2n} = \dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{p(1-p)}{1-(1-p)^2}+\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)^2} = \dfrac{2p-p^2}{2p-p^2} = 1$$